# All tableView Cells Show Same Artwork Image for Playlists

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitem

I have a `tableView` which shows a list of playlists from the user's music library.  The code I used to get this list is:

```
@implementation playlistsViewController
{
    NSArray *playlists;
    MPMediaQuery *playlistsQuery;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{        
    self.title = @"Playlists";

    playlistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
    playlists = [playlistsQuery collections]; 
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [playlists count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  ....

    // Configure the cell...

    MPMediaItem *rowItem = [playlists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [rowItem valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName];

    cell.imageView.image = [self getAlbumArtworkWithSize:(CGSizeMake(44,44))];

    return cell;
}
```

I then have `getAlbumArtworkWithSize`:

```
- (UIImage *) getAlbumArtworkWithSize: (CGSize) albumSize
{
    // IMAGE

    MPMediaQuery *playlistQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
    MPMediaPropertyPredicate *playlistPredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue: playlistTitle forProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName];
    [playlistQuery addFilterPredicate:playlistPredicate];

    for (MPMediaPlaylist *playlist in playlists) {
        NSLog (@"%@", [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName]);

        NSArray *songs = [playlist items];

        for (int i = 0; i < [songs count]; i++) {

            MPMediaItem *mediaItem = [songs objectAtIndex:i];
            UIImage *artworkImage;

            MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [mediaItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
            tempImage = [artwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake (1, 1)];

            if (tempImage) {
                tempImage = [artwork imageWithSize:albumSize];
                playlistImage = artworkImage;
                return artworkImage;
            }
        }
    }
return [UIImage imageNamed:@"Songs.png"];
}
```

*What this code does: it cycles through all songs in the playlist until it finds a song with album artwork, as some songs do not have any artwork.  Then it returns that image.*

However, this only returns *the same* artwork image for **all** cells in my table.  How do I run `getAlbumArtworkWithSize` for **each table view cell (playlist name)**?

This is what I currently get:

[image: This is what I currently get IMAGE]
.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're not iterating through the collection of items specific to the playlist belonging to that row in your `getAlbumArtworkWithSize` method. To make it easier and reduce execution time (not making an additional query in your method), try passing the collection to your function:

```
- (UIImage *)getAlbumArtworkWithSize:(CGSize)albumSize forPlaylist:(MPMediaItemCollection *)collection
{
    for (MPMediaItem *mediaItem in collection.items) {
        UIImage *artworkImage;

        MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [mediaItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
        tempImage = [artwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake (1, 1)];

        if (tempImage) {
            tempImage = [artwork imageWithSize:albumSize];
            playlistImage = artworkImage;
            return artworkImage;
        }
    }
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"Songs.png"];
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
cell.imageView.image = [self getAlbumArtworkWithSize:CGSizeMake(44,44) forCollection:[playlists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

I wouldn't recommend using this method, it could prove to be very slow with playlists containing ~1000 items. It's better to use the representative item of the collection and use a placeholder if no image is returned. Which would like something like this:

```
- (UIImage *)getAlbumArtworkWithSize:(CGSize)albumSize forPlaylist:(MPMediaItemCollection *)collection
{
        UIImage *artworkImage;

        MPMediaItem *mediaItem = [collection representativeItem];
        MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [mediaItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
        tempImage = [artwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake (1, 1)];

        if (tempImage) {
            tempImage = [artwork imageWithSize:albumSize];
            playlistImage = artworkImage;
            return artworkImage;
        }
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"Songs.png"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Why would my original method be slow with larger playlists if all it does is look for the first song that has album artwork?  Surely a song within the first 10 of a playlist will have one, no?  Just curious :)

Also, I used the second, more efficient method as you said, but it does not return a representative image for all of my playlists despite them having songs that have album artwork.  E.g. Top 25 Most Played - [My app](http://i62.tinypic.com/15mk6rc.jpg) despite the playlist having album artwork (see [music app](http://i62.tinypic.com/2zfny1y.png)).