# Is it possible to retrieve the music Playlist Artwork?

Tags: ios, swift3, playlist, artwork

I'm trying to retrieve the artwork for a playlist (not the artwork for a song).  The Apple music app let you create an image for a playlist but I can't seem to access it.

Is this possible?  MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork is not listed as one of the Playlist Property Keys.

I'm trying the following:

```
let playlistItems: [MPMediaPlaylist] = playlistQuery.collections! as! [MPMediaPlaylist]

    for playlist in playlistItems {

        let artwork = playlist.value( forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork ) as? MPMediaItemArtwork
        let sizeforArtwork = artwork?.bounds.size
        let artworkImage = artwork?.image(at: sizeforArtwork!)

        let playlistName = playlist.value( forProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName ) as! String

        let info: PlaylistInfo = PlaylistInfo(
            playlistTitle: playlistName,
            playlistImage: artworkImage
        )
        playlists.append(info)
    }
```

And

```
struct PlaylistInfo {
var playlistTitle: String
var playlistImage: UIImage?
}

var playlists: [PlaylistInfo] = []
```

Comment: Playlists do not have artwork. `MPMediaItem`s do. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741163/all-tableview-cells-show-same-artwork-image-for-playlists)

Comment: @shallowThought Playlists in the Apple Music app have images.  Also, I am using the MPMediaPickerController in my app and it also shows the playlist image for playlists that have an image. I've already seen that other question.  The poster was trying to get an image from a song in each playlist, not trying to get the playlist image.

Comment: I got the same problem. waiting for resolution